# Concatenate double from #define with string in C

Tags: c, string, double, concatenation

In C, I am trying to have the output files name include 2 of the variables for easy identification. These are initiated early on via `#define obj1 100` and `#define obj2 5`, and when it comes to the output I am after the filename to be something like `100_5_outputOfCode.txt`.

In order to get this to work I have tried

```
char fileName[1024];
strcpy(fileName, obj1);
strcat(fileName, "_");
strcat(fileName, obj2);
strcat(fileName, "_");
strcat(fileName, "outputOfCode.txt");
```

and then using `fileName` in the output function (which works normally). Instead I am getting an error saying `ror: passing 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'`.

From here I have tried to convert `obj1` and `obj2` to characters via `printf(obj1, %f)` however this has had no effect.

How can I achieve my goal of concatenating these objects to a character string? I have very little knowledge of C, so sorry if some of this is unclear.

Comment: Make the macros like `#define obj1 "100"` and `#define obj2 "5"`. With this your first approach should work.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to illustrate the problem. As it is, your description is very unclear. there is no "double" anywhere in your code. And which line of code does that error come from?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @Eraklon They are defined as numbers to be used as variables in my code, and so defining them as characters will result in more issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define obj1 100
```

gives you an *integer,* which you won't be able to use with `strcat` directly. If you wanted to do it that way, you would have to use a *string:*

```
#define obj1 "100"
```

However, you can keep what you have and just replace that code with a much simpler:

```
char fileName[1024];
sprintf(fileName, "%d_%d_outputOfCode.txt", obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: Or even: `char *filename = obj1 "_" obj2 "_outputOfCode.txt";` then

Comment: I have used the second part of your solution and it has worked perfectly! Thank you!